# Arbitrary distribution -> Uniform distribution (Probability Integral Transform?)

Tags: matlab, statistics, transform, distribution, probability

I have 500,000 values for a variable derived from financial markets. Specifically, this variable represents distance from the mean (in standard deviations). This variable has a arbitrary distribution. I need a formula that will allow me to select a range around any value of this variable such that an equal (or close to it) amount of data points fall within that range.

This will allow me to then analyze all of the data points within a specific range and to treat them as "similar situations to the input."

From what I understand, this means that I need to convert it from arbitrary distribution to uniform distribution. I have read (but barely understood) that what I am looking for is called  "probability integral transform."

Can anyone assist me with some code (Matlab preferred, but it doesn't really matter) to help me accomplish this?

Comment: The probability integral transform is just a function that you apply to your random variable in order to convert it to a uniform distribution.  Your question isn't very clear, though.  So you have something generating random data?  And you want to get data with a uniform distribution?  What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: @Oli I gather this variable from financial markets. Specifically, it represents the deviation away from the price's norm at a current point in time.

I want to be able to select a range around any possible value of this variable, such that the same amount of data points falls in this range.


This will allow me to then analyze all of the data points within a specific range and to treat them as "similar situations to the input"

Comment: Aha.  So you want to be able to select some mid-point of a range, and specify something like "I want the width of the range that captures e.g. 10% of the samples"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I put together quickly. It's not polished and not perfect, but it does what you want to do.

```
clear
randList=[randn(1e4,1);2*randn(1e4,1)+5];
[xCdf,xList]=ksdensity(randList,'npoints',5e3,'function','cdf');
xRange=getInterval(5,xList,xCdf,0.1);
```

and the function `getInterval` is

```
function out=getInterval(yPoint,xList,xCdf,areaFraction)
    yCdf=interp1(xList,xCdf,yPoint);
    yCdfRange=[-areaFraction/2, areaFraction/2]+yCdf;

    out=interp1(xCdf,xList,yCdfRange);
```

**Explanation:**

The CDF of the random distribution is shown below by the line in blue. You provide a point (here `5` in the input to `getInterval`) about which you want a range that gives you 10% of the area (input `0.1` to `getInterval`). The chosen point is marked by the red cross and the 
interval is marked by the lines in green. You can get the corresponding points from the original list that lie within this interval as

```
newList=randList(randList>=xRange(1) & randList<=xRange(2));
```

You'll find that on an average, the number of points in this example is ~2000, which is 10% of `numel(randList)`

```
numel(newList)

ans =

        2045
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- Please note that this was done quickly and I haven't made any checks to see if the chosen point is outside the range or if `yCdfRange` falls outside `[0 1]`, in which case `interp1` will return a `NaN`. This is fairly straightforward to implement, and I'll leave that to you.
- Also, `ksdensity` is very CPU intensive. I wouldn't recommend increasing `npoints` to more than `1e4`. I assume you're only working with a fixed list (i.e., you have a list of `5e5` points that you've obtained somehow and now you're just running tests/analyzing it). In that case, you can run `ksdensity` once and save the result.

Comment: Wow awesome! Thank you so much!! I am going to try it out in an hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

I do not speak Matlab, but you need to find quantiles in your data. This is Mathematica code which would do this:

```
In[88]:= data = RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[0, 1, 2], 10^4];
```

Compute quantile points:

```
In[91]:= q10 = Quantile[data, Range[0, 10]/10];
```

Now form pairs of consecutive quantiles:

```
In[92]:= intervals = Partition[q10, 2, 1];

In[93]:= intervals

Out[93]= {{-1.397, -0.136989}, {-0.136989, 0.123689}, {0.123689, 
  0.312232}, {0.312232, 0.478551}, {0.478551, 0.652482}, {0.652482, 
  0.829642}, {0.829642, 1.02801}, {1.02801, 1.27609}, {1.27609, 
  1.6237}, {1.6237, 4.04219}}
```

Verify that the splitting points separate data nearly evenly:

```
In[94]:= Table[Count[data, x_ /; i[[1]] <= x < i[[2]]], {i, intervals}]

Out[94]= {999, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000}
```